# Adding a class to a site published with the Tailwind CLI

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, cdn

When I create a site using the Tailwind CSS CLI, I know that only the classes I use are written to a file named `output.css`. When I want to make a change to the shared hosting website published with the obtained folder, I cannot because it is not monitored instantly (when I add a Tailwind class that I didn't use). Do I need to edit it locally and publish it every time for this process?

On the other hand, when I use Tailwind CSS CDN, everything works fine as I can include the entire library. But since the custom CSS and config settings I want to add will be in the head tag, it means that it must be read and run again on every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past time, I found a solution to the problem I shared above as follows.

As I always do, I created the site using the Tailwindcss CLI and published it with its own files. If I want to make a change after publishing, I added the Tailwindcss CDN script to the header and included the Tailwindcss library. Thus, while the classes I use are in my current style.css file, I have added the ones I do not use with the help of CDN. There will be no conflict of classes because the classes I already use are in the style.css file. While I think that this solution will be useful for small-scale website projects, I would like to point out that it will be inefficient for large-scale projects.

Answer (score 0):

**if you have just one update**

Well i don't know if my solution is the best or not , but this maybe help you , you can generate the classes that you want from
: https://play.tailwindcss.com/

and then create another css file with the new classes and upload it to the server

**if you have multiple updates**

the above method is not good when you have multiple updates , then you should copy and paste your new classes in the same css file that you already used and from the html you should add something in the end of the link for example ?cache=234923497
this will remove the cache for old version of the file

Comment: Thank you for your response but it seems like it wouldn't be true to include a new css for every update on the site.

Comment: @berkesasa you are right , this method is not good when you have multiple updates , then you should copy and paste your new classes in the same css file that you already used and from the html you should add something in the end of the link for example `?cache=234923497`

this will remove the cache for old version of the file

Comment: The answer to the question of whether I need to edit it locally and publish it every time for this process is then no. Thanks for your support, I'm still waiting for other answers in case there are different answers.